# Foreign Key query with unequal number of rows in data, that the remainders but remain

Tags: postgresql, error-handling, helper

[PostgreSQL code with error(https://i.stack.imgur.com/sHNQs.png)[Excel files with their rows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8tfKH.png)]

So my issue is that i want to reference/correlate each table with each other under the variable patientAMKA or patient. I get the error that you can see in the photo in postgresql. What i want is to correlate each other, without removing the rest unmatched rows from the other excel files. How do i do that?

Comment: Please [do not post a link to a painting of the error message](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/1048572)!

Comment: Please do **not** post code as images. See here for more details why: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551  and sample data is also better presented as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking tables.